# Is it possible to put click listener on a css box like this one in my case

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclicklistener

I learn React and Javascript and have this [Codesandbox projects](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-effect-react-forked-ey2ze?file=/src/App.js) and have tried to add like a
text "click to open" and then a popup show up. I think I have to redesign it maybe because css and click is not friends right?

On the app when the overlay slide out I want to click a button on the overlay something.

Is it possible to redesign using Reactjs Component somehow? So the that overlay is a Component that can take clicks?

any tips would be nice!

https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-effect-react-forked-ey2ze?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do you want to replace mouseEnter/mouseLeave with onClick?

Comment: The `mouseEnter/mouseLeave` are only for to control the overlay just the way I want it

Comment: did you try to add a button inside the overlay? ```<button onClick={() => { alert('Works'); } }>Click</button>``` I tried it and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I learn so much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add `onClick` to your overlay div.

see: [this condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-effect-react-forked-rd6j5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes that was what I wanted thanks. What if I wanted more functionality then just a a button maybe 5 buttons, text and options . Can this be migrated to Us a Component since functionality is heavier?